# Safari Extension - Message

Tags: javascript, safari, safari-extension

This is my first Safari extension and thus far I like it quiet a bit. I am trying to add an extension bar that interacts with an injected.js page and toggles items on the pages via the jquery .toggle();

I have been able to load jQuery into the page no issue, however when it comes to sending a message from the extension bar to the injected.js I am falling short. I have spent over 8 hours today reviewing the developer pages on Apple. The only thing I have managed to do is

Extension Bar:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Board Tools</title> <!-- Extension Bar -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        const myGlobal = safari.extension.globalPage.contentWindow;

    function ToggleBoard(){ 
        myGlobal.test();    
    }
</script>

</head>
<body>

    <input type="button" id="board" value="Board Toggle" onClick="ToggleBoard();">

</body>
</html>
```

Global HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>global page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function test() {
            alert("1");
            event.target.page.dispatchMessage("test", "test");
            alert("2");
    }

   </script>
</head>
<body> </body>
</html>
```

Injected.js:

```
function test(msgEvent) {
    alert(msgEvent.name);
}
// register for message events
safari.self.addEventListener("message", test, false);
```

I am able to call the ToggleBoard() function from the extension bar. The ToggleBoard() function can call the test() function from the Global HTML. When the test() function is called on the Global HTML page the fist alert fires, the second does not. I have narrowed it down at least that far. I get the way I am trying to send my message is probably wrong, but that is what is says here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/MessagesandProxies/MessagesandProxies.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009977-CH14-SW1

Just to see if it was a mistake on my part or something goofy with the development page I copied the exact code on their page and used just the Global HTML and Injected.js and I still did not get the result I was looking for.

Solved:
The answer I selected does apply a lot towards the issue I had. It was not the exact answer per-say but it did, along with the comments help me get my code straightened out. In order to get the various extension components to message properly I needed to set the Extension Remote Access to All, and then add URL patterns to the whitelist. My extension only fires on the pages I wanted and I can use messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `test` function in the global page, `event` does not refer to anything, since the function is not an event handler. If you want to target the active tab, use this instead:

```
safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab.page.dispatchMessage('test, 'test');
```

If, later, you find you want the extension bar or the global page to respond to messages from an injected script, you can add something like this in either place:

```
safari.application.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
    if (e.name === 'whatever') {
        e.target.page.dispatchMessage('foo', 'bar');
    }
}, false);
```

If you want to send a message from an injected script to the global page or an extension bar, use `safari.self.tab.dispatchMessage` and have a "message" event handler in place in the global page or extension bar.

Comment: This is getting me in the right direction. Ultimately what I really want is the injected script to respond to the extension bar.

Comment: Or have the Global HTML respond to the extension bar by toggling a div on the page.

Comment: So I did some playing around and if I set Extension Website Access to All instead of Some, I am able to use the example on this page: http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/AddingExtensionToolbars/AddingExtensionToolbars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009977-CH5-SW2  However when I set it to some and select my domain patterns message fails.

Comment: Use `safari.self.tab.dispatchMessage` to send a message from the injected script to the extension bar.

Comment: I want to go from Extension Bar -> Injected Script. Basically I have a function in the injected script that I want to be triggered when a button on the extension bar is clicked.

Comment: The same `safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab.page.dispatchMessage` can be used from within the extension bar to send a message to the injected script.

Comment: Ok so using the example you provided I can get the extension bar to talk to injected script. HOWEVER the only way I can get them to talk is if I set Extension Website Access to ALL. I don't want that with my extension, I want my extension set to some and I only want it to interact with 3 domain patterns. Why doesn't messages work when the Extension Website Access is set to Some?

Comment: AYE OHH!!!! I got it! If Extension Website Access is set to Some and I provide domain patterns, messages will not work between them. I dont know what this was just happening. If however I set Extension Website Access to All and then added URL patterns to the whitelist it worked.